# How to prevent pyInstaller temporary files from being deleted?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am creating an executable of Flask app by using `pyinstaller`. It allocates 10GB storage in the `_MEIPASS` folder under Temp directory. However, temporary files in `_MEIPASS` folder are removed when the program is terminated. It tooks long time to load all the files each startup. How can I prevent the `pyinstaller` temporary files from being deleted?

Comment: why do you remove it ? pyinstaller works in this way - it uncompresses .exe  to temporary folder and runs your script - and you shouldn't delete it. OR you should create without option  `onefile` and copy all files manually to other computer - and it will not have to uncompress it. Or you could use external tools to create installer to simply move on other computer and uncompress it.

Comment: @furas, _MEIPASS in the Temp directory is removed after terminating the exe and I actually want to prevent this. _MEIPASS shouldn't be removed when I terminate the exe. Because when I run the exe everytime it is uncompressed into the Temp folder again and it takes long time.

It should be uncompressed into the Temp folder once and when I run the exe again it should load the required files from that location.

Comment: @furas, Sorry. I misspelled it. I edited question.

Comment: you are wrong - `onefile` wasn't create to keep `_MEIPASS` - all idea of `onefile` is to uncompress .exe to termporary folder `_MEIPASS` and delete it when you terminate it. If you want to keep it then you should skip `onefile` to create folder with all files which you can copy on other computer. And you can use this folder with all files to create installer using other tools - like `NSIS` on Windows. As I remember this is described in documentation.

Comment: you need [Bundling to One Folder](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-folder) instead of `one file`

Comment: Thank you. I will create a setup file to extract required files into a specific folder. _MEIPASS folder was designed to provide secuirty according to [this answer](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/discussions/6765#discussioncomment-2600815) .